# java Browser with static url

Tags: java, browser

I was able to get this work by entering the url. but what i need is there is a string variable to link the url and **Autoload** this page. And also make a button to exit by entering the password popup and exit.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkEvent;
import javax.swing.event.HyperlinkListener;

public class main extends JFrame{

    private JTextField addressBar;
    private JEditorPane display;
    private String link = "http://www.google.lk";

    public main(){

        addressBar= new JTextField(link);
        addressBar.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        loadCrap(e.getActionCommand());
                    }
                }
                );
        add(addressBar,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        display = new JEditorPane();
        display.setEditable(false);
        display.addHyperlinkListener(
                new HyperlinkListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void hyperlinkUpdate(HyperlinkEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //if(e.getEventType()==HyperlinkEvent.EventType.ACTIVATED){
                            loadCrap(e.getURL().toString());
                        //}

                    }
                }
                );
        add(new JScrollPane(display), BorderLayout.CENTER);


    }

    private void loadCrap(String usertext){
        try{
            display.setPage(usertext);
            addressBar.setText(usertext);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Shit!");
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame browser = new main();
        browser.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        browser.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

        browser.setUndecorated(true);

        browser.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `.setPage`

This will load the page to the url within the parenthesis.

Here is an example:

```
        try {
        display.setPage("http://www.google.lk");
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is your full code: http://pastebin.com/ki4bs4kC

Comment: can you tell me with full coding??